# curl 8.4.0 source is missing some .h files

Tags: visual-studio-2010, winapi, node-libcurl

I downloaded the 8.4.0 cURL source files (released Oct. 11) and am attempting the compile libcurl.lib using Visual Studio 2010. The source package comes with a solution file for VC10 (thank you!) but compiling it generates many errors, such as "missing libssh2.h". I attempted to find the missing header files online, and had some success (assuming they are the correct ones for win32), but adding each one only gives rise to new missing header files. Is there a better way to fix this? Thanks in advance.

I did a Google search for the missing header files, and added them to the source file folder. That took care of the original error message, but then generated new error messages about missing headers referenced in the file I added. I am not at all sure the header files I found online were intended for the win32 environment I am using.

Comment: the curl doc has information on dependencies. https://everything.curl.dev/build/deps

Comment: Thanks for the link. My question relates to the source code bundle -- not all the required headers appear to be present. How does one go about finding the correct missing ones?